# Parse a section of text out of a cell

Tags: parsing, range, extract

I have a cell that keeps adding 'sections' to the cell based on user activity, with the most recent on top, (so duplicates can occur).  An example of one of the cells is:

```
STATUS: PRELOAD ERROR: : 
NOTE: N/A
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:45:37 PM
 ---------------------------------------- 
STATUS: PRELOAD ERROR: GPS PRELOAD IS MISSING: GPS
NOTE: EMPLOYEE DEAL
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:45:37 PM
 ---------------------------------------- 
STATUS: PRELOAD ERROR: PRELOAD IS MISSING: THEFT
NOTE: EMPLOYEE DEAL
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:45:37 PM
 ---------------------------------------- 
STATUS: PRELOAD ERROR: PRELOAD IS MISSING: APPERANCE
NOTE: EMPLOYEE DEAL
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:45:37 PM
 ---------------------------------------- 
STATUS: CLEANED
NOTE: PRINTED RECAP SHEET
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:45:37 PM
 ---------------------------------------- 
STATUS: HOUSE DEAL ENTRY
NOTE: EMPLOYEE DEAL
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:44:54 PM
 ---------------------------------------- 
STATUS: CLEANED
NOTE: PRINTED RECAP SHEET
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:44:54 PM
 ----------------------------------------
```

I want to be able to extract the most recent "STATUS: HOUSE DEAL ENTRY" section which would include the 3 lines after it. The result should be:

```
STATUS: HOUSE DEAL ENTRY
NOTE: EMPLOYEE DEAL
BY: SMITH, JOHN
AT: 3/20/2020 2:44:54 PM
```

how can I do it with VBA or is it possible with an Excel formula?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
Dim StatusHistory As String
Dim FindHouse() As String

StatusHistory = FILOGData.Range("T1277").Value
FindHouse = Split(StatusHistory, " ---------------------------------------- ")

For i = 0 To UBound(FindHouse)

If InStr(FindHouse(i), "STATUS: HOUSE DEAL ENTRY") > 0 Then
        MsgBox FindHouse(i)
End If

Next i
```

Thoughts?